# Storing Multiple User Inputs from a ListBox using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, multipleselection

I am trying to have the user select multiple options from an **ActiveX** ListBox (ListBoxTest1) and then have their selections stored in separate rows on another sheet. I keep getting the error "Unable to get the ListBoxes property of the Worksheet class" when the first line shown here is about to be executed.

```
Set listX = Sheets("Availability Criteria").ListBoxes("ListBoxTest1")

With listX
    For i = 1 To .ListCount
        If .Selected(i) Then
            Sheets("WorkingSheet").Cells(i + 4, "F").Value = .Items(i)
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

I thought the .Items property was what I needed to take the input from the ListBox, but perhaps that's the illegal property in question. All of my code is in the modules section, not a private sub.

I'm still very new to Excel's VBA....please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Worksheet` actually doesn't have a `ListBoxes` property natively, and `Sheets("Availability Criteria")` returns a strongly typed `Worksheet`. Probably the simplest way to access the collection is to late-bind the `Worksheet`:

```
Dim sh As Object
Set sh = Sheets("Availability Criteria")
Set listX = sh.ListBoxes("ListBoxTest1")
```

**EDIT**

The above code only applies to Form Controls.  For ActiveX controls, you need to access them via the `OLEObjects` collection:

```
Dim listX As MSForms.ListBox
Set listX = Sheets("Availability Criteria").OLEObjects("ListBoxTest1").Object

With listX
    For i = 1 To .ListCount
        If .Selected(i) Then
            Sheets("WorkingSheet").Cells(i + 4, "F").Value = .List(i)
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: hm. I put this above the code I have pasted in my question and I still get the same run-time error as before "Unable to get the ListBoxes property of the Worksheet class." Was this code meant to be put in a private sub for the worksheet?

Comment: I had the wrong `ListBox` name (was using the one from my test code). I was running this from the Worksheet's module.

Comment: I noticed that and fixed it when I was testing it originally

Comment: This is my code now: 
Dim lstX As ListBox 

Dim sh As Object
Set sh = Sheets("Availability Criteria")
Set listX = sh.ListBoxes("ListBoxTest1")



'Set listX = Sheets("Availability Criteria").ListBoxes("ListBoxTest1")

With listX
    For i = 1 To .ListCount
        If .Selected(i) Then
            Sheets("WorkingSheet").Cells(i + 4, "F").Value = .AddItem(i)<br/>
        End If
    Next i
End With

Comment: @Fahvs - I can't replicate an error as long as everything is declared correctly. Note that you have `Dim lstX As ListBox`, but `Set listX = ...`.

Comment: Thanks SO SO much for your help. That "set" issue was definitely a rookie mistake. I took it out and I'm still getting the same error as before. Should this be a private sub?

Comment: I'm using an ActiveX Listbox also...I'm thinking that might be part of the problem

Comment: @Fahvs - That's definitely the problem.  See the edit.

Comment: Dude, you are a reverend saint. The program is now putting the list selections in the right spot, but it looks like it's getting stuck in the loop. I'm getting the error "Could not get the selected property. Invalid argument." It looks like it's having a hard time determining when there are no more selections to be iterated over. Did this happen for you? Really, really appreciate the help.

Comment: I think I found the issue: maybe the number of times the loop needs to be iterated is like this: For i = 1 To .ListCount - 1 
plz update your solution so I can mark it as the incredible life-saver it has been.

Comment: @Fahvs - That's a quirk of column headers.  If you have `.ColumnHeads` set to `True` it's included in the `.ListCount`. You can either subtract 1 (as you found out) or set `.ColumnHeads` to `False`.